# setting text file as username and password to validate login

Tags: javascript

So I have this set up correctly, because I can check with document.write and it displays exactly what the text file has. However, when I use it to validate a login page it doesn't work it will always be an unsuccessful login.. Is it because the text in the textfile has some extra added garbage to it ?

```js
function readTextFile(file)
{
 var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
 rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
 rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
 {
if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
{

                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
       intoArray(allText);
}
}
rawFile.send(null);
}

function intoArray (allText) {
  
lineArr = allText.split('\n'); 

var username = lineArr[0];
var password = lineArr[1];
validateForm(username, password);
}
 
function validateForm(username, password) {
    var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
    var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
  
    if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
    window.location="loginsuccess.html";
       return false;
    }
    else {
        alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and 
password");
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

The text file has this :

```
username
password
```

Comment: You are setting your password variable in a callback, but when you actually use it, it does not exist yet. You should consider learning some more basics.

Comment: Edited with passing by value... still not sure why it won't work. Changed the onSubmit="return validateForm()" to onSubmit="readTextFile('info.txt')" so that it will work with the values in order and still nothing.

Comment: The thing is this: you need to move everything that relies on an already-read username and password *into* your asynchronous file reading callback. Besides that: client-side authentication is completely useless as you can *never* rely on that. Did you consider using ajax to do the checking server-side?

Comment: This is a homework assignment I'm not considering anything for a real website. I'm doing this for a grade.